# Referential Integrity on NHibernate with an Abstract Class

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have this situation, a Product base class which is abstract and two concrete subclasses (Car, Bike). Then an Invoice which owns a collection of InvoiceItem. InvoiceItem reference a Product instance.
Here is the hbms:

Product Class

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
               assembly="MyAssembly"
               namespace="MyNamespace">
<class name="Product" abstract="true">
    <id name="Id" column="id">
        <generator class="guid.comb" />
    </id>
    <property name="Code" column="code" type="string" not-null="true" />
    <property name="Name" column="name" type="string" not-null="true" />
    
    <set name="Items" inverse="true">
        <key column="productId" />
        <one-to-many class="InvoiceItem"/>
    </set>
    <union-subclass name="Car" table="Cars">
        <property name="EngineName" column="engineName" not-null="true" />
        </union-subclass>
        <union-subclass name="Bike" table="Bikes">
            <property name="ShifterSpeedCount" column="shifterSpeedCount" type="int" not-null="true" />
        </union-subclass>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

InvoiceItem Class

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
               assembly="MyAssembly"
               namespace="MyNamespace">
<class name="InvoiceItem" table="InvoiceItems">
    <id name="Id" column="id">
        <generator class="guid.comb" />
    </id>

    <property name="Price" column="price" precision="15" scale="3" not-null="true" />
    <property name="Count" column="count" type="int" not-null="true" />
    <many-to-one name="Product" column="productId" foreign-key="FK_ProductInvoiceItems"  />
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

The problem I have is that when I Delete an instance of Car, NHibernate doesn't checks the integrity in InvoiceItem, so after the delete, I have a broken reference, causing problems.

The problem is caused because of the inheritance, the productId column can't reference to a single table, causing that NHibernate doesn't generate the FK.

This scenario is extremely simple, so may be check the reference manually is simple. But how can I solve this problem in a more complex project?
Is there a way to force NHibernate to check the Integrity automatically?

Comment: Have you tried cascade all-delete-orphan on the invoiceitem set?

Comment: No, If I add all-delete-orphan to the InvoiceItem set then the referenced InvoiceItem will be deleted!

Comment: so...you want the invoice items to have their product id set to null? I think Cascade all would do that...

Comment: Nope, I want an Exception or some kind of restriction

Comment: so..... you say "I have a broken reference, causing problems." and I assume one of those problems is a SQL FK constraint violation resulting in an exception?!?!?! there ya go, you answered your own question. ;) otherwise, maybe setup some pre delete validation logic, possibly inside an IPreDeleteEventListener....

Comment: Because Product is an abstract class, there's NO SQL FK CONSTRAINTS in the InvoiceItems table. If Product was a concrete class and InvoiceItem was referring to it, then I will have a FK CONSTRAINT in the database. Thanks anyway!

Comment: than what is this `<many-to-one name="Product" column="productId" foreign-key="FK_ProductInvoiceItems"  />` looks like an FK to me? I have no idea what you want anymore.

Comment: In spite of there is a foreign-key="FK_ProductInvoiceItems" in the mapping file, there is no such foreign key restriction generated in the database. This seems to be imposible because of Product is an abstract class, so there is no Products table in the database.

Comment: ohhhhhhhhhhh ok, hmmm I usually avoid the inheritance mapping. Can you change that so there is a Product table and extra tables for each sub class? Otherwise, you'd need a separate many-to-many for each subclass to invoice item set.

Answer (score 1):

implement an `IPreDeleteEventListener` and pseudocode

```
Product p = entity as Product;
if (p != null && p.InvoiceItems.Count > 0)
    throw new MyException();
```